# How can I assign a value to an Access Combobox?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, variable-assignment

I have a form (FrmAddBookReviews) that is opened when certain events in another form (FrmAddArticles) occur.
I want to initialize the FrmAddBookReviews with some values from FrmAddArticles. It works fine except for the Author of the book review who I have in 2 comboboxes, where I want to write the first name in one and the last name in the other combobox. I do not want to use an unbound textbox, because I want the value of the primary key of the reviewer to appear in the table belonging to FrmAddBookReviews.
If I do (rstauth.Fields(0) is the primary key to TabAuth)

```
Me!cmbFnam.SetFocus
  Me!cmbFnam.Selected(1) = True
  Me.cmbFnam.Column(1) = rstauth.Fields(1).Value
```

I get run time error 424: Object required
I have tried a DLookup to get the name followed by

```
 Me.cmbFnam.Column(1) = strFnam
```

gives "the value does not match this field", in spite of the fact that column 1 of the combobox is text (but the control-source is the id of the reviewer). the same happens when I do

```
Me.cmbFnam.Column(1) = rstauth.Fields(1).Value
```

I have also tried to give the row-number in the Columns-clause. This gives me the "object required" error.

Can I get any help?

Biorn Veiro

Comment: Is that a multi-select combobox, or a normal combobox?

Comment: It is a normal combobox. I want to show the first name of an author, where I have the primary key of the authors table available.

Comment: Why do you have author name split into two comboboxes? Why not one combobox and save the AuthorID into record? Reference combobox columns by index. Index begins with 0. If value is in column 1, its index is 0; column 2 has index 1, etc. But you can't 'set' the value of combobox Column, you set combobox Value. Remove the Column(1) and default to Value property.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It works now, but when I used one combobox I could only display one name, so I went back to my original two with first name in one and last name in the other.